# Se puede hacer un insert despues de un select en PHP Y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

me acerco a ustedes preguntando sobre una funcion que pretendo hacer, resulta que tengo 2 servers en la misma red, me interesaria mucho saber si es posible atravez de un SCRITP, programa o algun query hacer una consulta al server y el resultado que me arroje insertarlo en otra base alojada en otro server, se pretende que cada cierto tiempo se corra una tarea programa con este programa y copie todos los registros nuevos del query a la base alojada en otro server, buscando en internet me encontre con este ejemplo en PHP, que opinan creen que sea la manera correcta o existe otra manera de hacerlo?

Dejo el Query de la consulta.

```
  PEFECHA AS 'FECHA',
  PEALMACEN AS 'TIENDA',
  PLTIPMV,
  PENUM AS 'No. Pedido',
  IFAM1 AS 'TIPO',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(IDESCR," ",1) AS 'NOMBRE',
MID(ICOD,7,3) AS 'COLOR',
MID(ICOD,11,3) AS 'TALLA',
  ICOD  AS 'SKU',
  PLCANT AS 'PZ',
  PLPRECI AS 'PRECIO',
  PLCLASE AS 'AGOTADO', /*N=NEGADO*/
  PLASIGNADO AS 'PZ ASIG',
  PESTATUS AS 'STATUS', /*SURT = PAGADO)*/
  PESPEDIDO AS 'PRIORIDAD',/*4=PAGADO 1=PENDIENTE*/
  PEDATE3
FROM
  FPENC
LEFT JOIN
  FPLIN ON FPLIN.PESEQ=FPENC.PESEQ
LEFT JOIN
  FINV ON FINV.ISEQ=FPLIN.ISEQ
WHERE
  PEFECHA BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-10-04'
AND
  PENUM IN('P0014333','P0014394','P0014397')
/*AND
  PESPEDIDO='4'*/
ORDER BY
  PENUM;
```

[image: Como pueden ver esa consulta es la que me interesa hacer un insert a otra base alojada en otro server. Dejo el codigo que encontre en internet.]

Como pueden ver esa consulta es la que me interesa hacer un insert a otra base alojada en otro server. Dejo el codigo que encontre en internet.

```
<?php
$L1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user1', 'pass1');
$DB1 = mysql_select_db('database1', $L1);

$L2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user2', 'pass2');
$DB2 = mysql_select_db('database2', $L2);

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1",$L1);
while($i=mysql_fetch_assoc($re))
{
    $u=array();
    foreach($i as $k=>$v) if($k!=$keyfield) $u[]="$k='$v'";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table2 (".implode(',',array_keys($i)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$i)."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(',',$u),$L2) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Que es lo mas reconmendable en estos casos, la verdad soy nuevo en esto y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Tu pregunta está basandose en opiniones, por lo que podría terminar cerrada. Lo que dices, es totalmente posible, cargar datos de una a otra por medio de un script. Lo que no entiendo, es que problema tienes al hacerlo...

Comment: No se como hacerlo, es la duda.

Comment: Espera, no entiendo, el código que has compartido, siquiera lo has probado? funciona?

Comment: No lo he probado, me estoy adelantando un poco a sus opiniones y sugerencias de como hacerlo. No se si funcione.

Comment: Bueno, como dije, sobre opiniones y sugerencias, la pregunta terminará siendo cerrada, por que lo que hace el sitio, es resolver problemas de programacion. Digamos que tu codigo termina no funcionando, ahi es cuando vienes a preguntar que esta mal, y explicas que no funciona y etc...

Comment: Ok, lo pruebo y subo los posibles escenarios que me pueda encontrar, gracias.

Comment: lamento comentarte que el sitio tiene una orientación Q&A y no vemos temas basados en opiniones y sugerencias... Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: es muy probable que tu post sea cerrado o reciba votos negativos; te recomiendo mejorar el post editándolo y dando un escenario e el que tengas un problema precisamente exacto en tu código. cualquier cosa estamos aquí para ayudarte.